# How to make Vue use a different value than the value property in form fields?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internationalization

I've got quite a singular issue. Say this:

```
<select name="screw[type]" v-model="form.screw.type">
   <option value="My value" ><?php _e('My value', 'fiam'); ?></option>
   //[...]
```

Naturally, somewhere else I'm doing this:

```
{{ form.screw.type }} // will write "My value"
```

Fine. Ehm.. Nope. Because I need that string to be translated. But I can't do it right in the field's value, because I need to send it untraslated. So in other words:

- I need not to translate the field's value
- I need to translate what Vue is going to write (like the option's label)

I wish I could do something like this:

```
<option value="My value" data-tvalue="<?php _e('My value', 'fiam'); ?>" ><?php _e('My value', 'fiam'); ?></option>

(for who of you didn't know, _e() is just a WordPress i18n function)
```

And then have Vue using `data-tvalue` instead of `value` when outputting. Is it somehow possible?

Comment: Have you tried using a computed value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I ended up creating a 'shadow' property and changing it via the `watch` function. Note that I'm referencing the SELECT via the custom `ref` prop and `Vue.$refs`. So:

```
<select name="screw[type]" ref="screw_type_select" v-model="form.screw.type">
   <option value="My value" data-value="<?php _e('My value', 'context'); ?>"><?php _e('My value', 'context'); ?></option>
   //[...]
```

Then in Vue:

```
var vueapp = new Vue({
  el: '#form'
  ,data:{
    form:{
      ,screw:{
        type: "Svasata Piana"
        ,type_t: "Svasata Piana"
      }
    }
  }// data
  ,watch:{
    'form.screw.type':function(){
      var select = this.$refs.screw_type_select;
      this.form.screw.type_t = select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-value')
    }
  }
});
```

Then again in html:

```
{{ form.screw.type_t }} // instead of {{ form.screw.type }}
```